# Skew the shadow, not the content

Tags: css

Consider:

```
<div class="my-class">
  AAA
</div>
```

I am trying to only skew the shadow, but not the content of the `div` by putting the shadow into the pseudo-element:

```
.my-class {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 10rem;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0.2em -0.4rem 0 -0em rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transform: skew(0, 25deg);
  }
}
```

The example appears in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/conusipiro/1/edit?html,css,output).

I am obviously misunderstanding something about pseudo-elements, because the shadow doesn't even appear. What am I missing and how can this code be fixed to skew the shadow, but not the text?

Comment: add `display`, `width` and `height` properties, then it should work. Your Pseudo element is atm 0x0

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nogugedema/1/edit?html,css,output start from here as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things. The pseudo element needs width and height - and the snippet below assumes those are to be the same as its 'owning' element.

Also, where is the element to be placed? This snippet assumes that what is wanted is the shadow skewed but as if it were otherwise the shadow on the main element so it positions it absolutely relative to the main element. Obviously change this if I've misunderstood.

```css
.my-class {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 10rem;
  position: relative;
}

.my-class::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0.2em -0.4rem 0 -0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform: skew(0, 25deg);
}


}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  AAA
</div>
```